# iOS OpenGL ES perform pinch zoom in 2d world

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, pinchzoom

I am making a 2d OpenGL app on iPad. And i need to implement a pinch/zoom.

I want to move the camera in `(x,y)` plane and control camera `x,y` and `z` value with pinch gesture.

Each frame in `update` method i make view matrix (camera) like this

`lookAt = GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt(view_x, view_y, view_z, view_x, view_y, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);`

where view_x, view_y and view_z are defined at program start like this:
`view_x = view_y = 0.0f; view_z = kStartZoom;`
kStartZoom is 3000.
So the camera is at (0,0,3000) and looks to (0,0,0)

The almost-working solution for handling pinch events is

```
- (IBAction) handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*) recognizer {
switch (recognizer.state)
{
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
    {
        if (recognizer.numberOfTouches == 2)
        {
            prevTouchOrigin1 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
            prevTouchOrigin2 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:1 inView:self.view];
        }
    } break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
    {
        if (recognizer.numberOfTouches == 2)
        {
            CGFloat newDistance, oldDistance;

            oldDistance = distanceBetweenTwoCGPoints(&prevTouchOrigin1, &prevTouchOrigin2);
            currTouchOrigin1 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
            currTouchOrigin2 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:1 inView:self.view];

            newDistance = distanceBetweenTwoCGPoints(&currTouchOrigin1, &currTouchOrigin2);

            if (newDistance == 0 || oldDistance == 0)
            {
                scaleFactor = 1;
            } else {
                scaleFactor = oldDistance / newDistance;
            }

            GLfloat check = view_z * scaleFactor;
            if (check < kMinZoom || check > kMaxZoom)
                return;

            view_z *= scaleFactor;

            // translate

            // formula: newPos = currTouchOrigin + (objectOrigin - prevTouchOrigin) * scaleFactor

            static CGPoint translationDelta;
            GLfloat z_ratio = view_z_old / view_z;

            newPos1.x = currTouchOrigin1.x - ((prevTouchOrigin1.x - view_x) * scaleFactor);
            newPos1.y = currTouchOrigin1.y - ((prevTouchOrigin1.y - view_y) * scaleFactor);

            newPos2.x = currTouchOrigin2.x - ((prevTouchOrigin2.x - view_x) * scaleFactor);
            newPos2.y = currTouchOrigin2.y - ((prevTouchOrigin2.y - view_y) * scaleFactor);

            midpoint = CGPointMidpoint(&newPos1, &newPos2);

            translationDelta = CGPointMake(midpoint.x - view_x, midpoint.y - view_y);

            view_x += translationDelta.x;
            view_y -= translationDelta.y;

            prevTouchOrigin1 = currTouchOrigin1;
            prevTouchOrigin2 = currTouchOrigin2;
        }
    } break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
    {
    } break;
    default :
    {
    }
}}
```

Allmost working.

I have more movement on x,y then i need so camera is weaving around.

Is the problem i am not applying some transforms from screen coord to world coords?

What can be the issue? Other examples i was looking into only modify camera position depending on distance between previous and last finger positions, which is what i am doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution:

I have two classes, one that takes care of all the OpenGL stuff (RenderViewController) and another one that takes care of all the gesture recognizers and communication between the OpenGL part and other parts of the app (EditViewController).

This is the code regarding the gestures:

**EdtorViewController**

It captures the gestures and send the info about them to the RenderViewController. You have to be careful because of the different coordinate systems.

```
- (void) generateGestureRecognizers {

    //Setup gesture recognizers
    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *twoFingersRotate = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(twoFingersRotate:)];
    [self.hitView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingersRotate];

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *twoFingersScale = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(twoFingersScale:)];
    [self.hitView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingersScale];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *oneFingerPan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerPan:)];
    [self.hitView addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerPan];


    [twoFingersRotate setDelegate:self];
    [twoFingersScale setDelegate:self];
    [oneFingerPan setDelegate:self];
}

- (void) oneFingerPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {    

    //Handle pan gesture
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.hitView];
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.hitView];

    //Send info to renderViewController
    [self.renderViewController translate:traslation];

    //Reset recognizer so change doesn't accumulate
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.hitView];    
}

- (void) twoFingersRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {  

    //Handle rotation gesture
    CGPoint locationInView = [recognizer locationInView:self.hitView];
    locationInView = CGPointMake(locationInView.x - self.hitView.bounds.size.width/2, locationInView.y - self.hitView.bounds.size.height/2);

    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        //Send info to renderViewController
        [self.renderViewController rotate:locationInView degrees:recognizer.rotation];

        //Reset recognizer
        [recognizer setRotation:0.0];
    }
}

- (void) twoFingersScale:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {

    //Handle scale gesture
    CGPoint locationInView = [recognizer locationInView:self.hitView];
    locationInView = CGPointMake(locationInView.x - self.hitView.bounds.size.width/2, locationInView.y - self.hitView.bounds.size.height/2);

    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        //Send info to renderViewController
        [self.renderViewController scale:locationInView ammount:recognizer.scale];

        //reset recognizer
        [recognizer setScale:1.0];
    }

}

//This allows gestures recognizers to happen simultaniously
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.view != otherGestureRecognizer.view)
        return NO;

    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]] || [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

**RenderViewController**

For every frame, the modelViewMatrix is calculated from three other temporary matrices (translation, scale and rotation)

```
- (void) setup {

    //Creates the modelViewMatrix from the initial position, rotation and scale
    translatemt = GLKMatrix4Translate(GLKMatrix4Identity, initialPosition.x, initialPosition.y, 0.0);
    scalemt = GLKMatrix4Scale(GLKMatrix4Identity, initialScale, initialScale, 1.0);
    rotatemt = GLKMatrix4Rotate(GLKMatrix4Identity, initialRotation, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    self.modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(GLKMatrix4Multiply(GLKMatrix4Multiply(translatemt, rotatemt), scalemt), GLKMatrix4Identity);

    //set these back to identities to take further modifications (they'll update the modelViewMatrix)
    scalemt = GLKMatrix4Identity;
    rotatemt = GLKMatrix4Identity;
    translatemt = GLKMatrix4Identity;


    //rest of the OpenGL setup
    [self setupOpengGL];

}

//public interface
- (void) translate:(CGPoint) location {
    //Update the translation temporary matrix
    translatemt = GLKMatrix4Translate(translatemt, location.x, -location.y, 0.0);
}

//public interface
- (void) rotate:(CGPoint) location degrees:(CGFloat) degrees {
    //Update the rotation temporary matrix
    rotatemt = GLKMatrix4Translate(GLKMatrix4Identity, location.x, -location.y, 0.0);
    rotatemt = GLKMatrix4Rotate(rotatemt, -degrees, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    rotatemt = GLKMatrix4Translate(rotatemt, -location.x, location.y, 0.0);
}

//public interface
- (void) scale:(CGPoint) location ammount:(CGFloat) ammount {
    //Update the scale temporary matrix
    scalemt = GLKMatrix4Translate(GLKMatrix4Identity, location.x, -location.y, 0.0);
    scalemt = GLKMatrix4Scale(scalemt, ammount, ammount, 1.0);
    scalemt = GLKMatrix4Translate(scalemt, -location.x, location.y, 0.0);
}

- (void)update {

    //this is done before every render update. It generates the modelViewMatrix from the temporary matrices
    self.modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(GLKMatrix4Multiply(GLKMatrix4Multiply(rotatemt, translatemt), scalemt), self.modelViewMatrix);

    //And then set them back to identities
    translatemt = GLKMatrix4Identity;
    rotatemt = GLKMatrix4Identity;
    scalemt = GLKMatrix4Identity;

    //set the modelViewMatrix for the effect (this is assuming you are using OpenGL es 2.0, but it would be similar for previous versions
    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = self.modelViewMatrix;
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to make this approach working for exactly 3 hours and have failed :) But still, even if it was working, i need to move camera not objects. When we have a lot of objects, modifying matrix of each object can get costly... Thank you Odrakir for effort. By reading your answer i got the idea for solution. I need to set ratio for input from screen. I'll write more when this is done.

Comment: I'm sorry but you shouldn't have one modelViewMatrix for every object. It's just one matrix for the whole program.

Comment: I dont follow. To recap: there is one model matrix for each object, which determines where object is in world space. Then we have one view and one projection matrix for camera. That is how i learned it from DirectX. In OpenGL should be the same, view matrix determines where camera looks and projection matrix deals with near and far planes and other stuff. Correct me if you think otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that's right. One model matrix for every independently moved object and only one view matrix for the camera (in my case all objects are static or move at the same time, that's why I combined both matrices). So, in your case, all those calculations I posted only have to get done once (for the view matrix) and then concatenate that with the model matrix for every object.

Comment: Ok, solved it. I'll post the code tomorrow but i'll mark your answer as correct because it moved me in right direction. And i know you invested time in writing all of this so you'll get the points.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your question but for pinch recognition I use UIPinchGestureRecongizer:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPinchGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Comment: i dont know how to put it better. I need to use pinch gesture for pinch zoom in OpenGL ES 2.0 That's it. And issues i have are described above.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses moving camera above x,y plane. 
The world stays static.
We are on some z position and we control camera movement by pinch gesture.

What was needed was conversion of units from screen space, expressed in points, to open gl space, expressed in discrete units.

I got this constant by drawing 50x50 square in opengl units on x,y plane, 
with camera centered `x = 0, y = 0, z = 100`.

Then i added two `UIView`s and set up pan gesture to move those two views. 
By panning gesture i physically centered their frame origins to upper right and lower right corners of opengl square.
The tap gesture was set to `NSLog` their origins.
That's how i got this constant:

```
static const GLfloat k = 0.125f; // 445 CG units is 50 discrete OpenGL units at Z = 100; 0.112359f
```

So for arbitrary camera z position i could calculate how much to scale those increments we get from pinch zoom finger positions.

Matrix initialization in some init method:

```
aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 5000.0f);
lookAt = GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt(view_x, view_y, view_z, view_x, view_y, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

All ivar's:

```
GLfloat view_x;
GLfloat view_y;
GLfloat view_z;
GLfloat view_z_base;

CGPoint currTouchOrigin1, currTouchOrigin2;
CGPoint prevTouchOrigin1, prevTouchOrigin2;
CGPoint newPos1, newPos2;
CGPoint midpoint;
CGFloat scaleFactor;
```

We move camera by view_x, view_y and view_z ivars.

All constants:

```
static const GLfloat k              = 0.125f; // 445 CG units is 50 discrete OpenGL units at Z = 100; 0.112359f
static const GLfloat default_z      = 100.0f;
static const GLfloat kMinZoom       = 30.0f;
static const GLfloat kMaxZoom       = 4000.0f;
static const GLfloat kStartZoom     = 200.0f;
```

This is full pinch zoom handler:

```
- (IBAction) handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*) recognizer {

switch (recognizer.state)
        {
            case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            {
                if (recognizer.numberOfTouches == 2)
                {
                    prevTouchOrigin1 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
                    prevTouchOrigin2 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:1 inView:self.view];
                }
            } break;
            case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            {
                if (recognizer.numberOfTouches == 2)
                {
                    CGFloat newDistance, oldDistance;

            oldDistance = distanceBetweenTwoCGPoints(&prevTouchOrigin1, &prevTouchOrigin2);
            currTouchOrigin1 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
            currTouchOrigin2 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:1 inView:self.view];

            newDistance = distanceBetweenTwoCGPoints(&currTouchOrigin1, &currTouchOrigin2);

            if (newDistance == 0 || oldDistance == 0)
            {
                scaleFactor = 1;
                //break;
            } else {
                //scaleFactor = oldDistance / newDistance;
                scaleFactor = newDistance / oldDistance;
            }

            GLfloat view_z_old = view_z;
            view_z /= scaleFactor;
            if (view_z < kMinZoom || view_z > kMaxZoom)
            {
                view_z = view_z_old;
                return;
            }

            // translate

            // formula: newPos = currTouchOrigin + (objectOrigin - prevTouchOrigin) * scaleFactor

            //static CGPoint tmp1, tmp2;
            static CGPoint translationDelta;

            newPos1.x = currTouchOrigin1.x - ((prevTouchOrigin1.x - (screenRect.size.width / 2)) * scaleFactor);
            newPos1.y = currTouchOrigin1.y - ((prevTouchOrigin1.y - (screenRect.size.height / 2)) * scaleFactor);

            newPos2.x = currTouchOrigin2.x - ((prevTouchOrigin2.x - (screenRect.size.width / 2)) * scaleFactor);
            newPos2.y = currTouchOrigin2.y - ((prevTouchOrigin2.y - (screenRect.size.height / 2)) * scaleFactor);

            midpoint = CGPointMidpoint(&newPos1, &newPos2);

            translationDelta = CGPointMake(midpoint.x - (screenRect.size.width / 2), midpoint.y - (screenRect.size.height / 2));

            static GLfloat r = 0.0f;
            static GLfloat k2 = 0.0f;

            r = view_z / default_z;
            k2 = k * r;

            // In openGL, coord sys if first quadrant based
            view_x += -translationDelta.x * k2;
            view_y +=  translationDelta.y * k2;

            // store current coords for next event
            prevTouchOrigin1 = currTouchOrigin1;
            prevTouchOrigin2 = currTouchOrigin2;
        }
    } break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
    {

    } break;
    default :
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is solution to my question. However i have marked Odrakir's answer as correct as his answer helped me to go into right direction. Also he devoted time. I have asked these kind of questions before and got no reply at all. Thanx Odrakir.